# Onclick animate img onto img and fade out

Tags: image, css, animation, onclick

I have a div with a background-image. I would like to have a function
onclick of the div an image of equal width and height fades in over the original div and fades out again.

Websearch gives me solutions with buttons, I would really like a solution without a button that stays visible.

I'm having trouble with the on click fade part and getting the new image on top of the old one. I know about img-swap but I would like an animation.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Please share the code you've already prepared.

Answer (score -1):

There are probably a lot of ways to do this...here's one using a pseudo-element and JQuery (for the click event).

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/Lgvfn)

HTML

```
<div class="clicker"> </div> /* note no content - not always appropriate */
```

CSS

```
.clicker {
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
  margin:10px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  background:url(http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-250-250-6.jpg);
  /* default bg image */
  position:relative;

}

.active:after {
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background:url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-250-250-5.jpg);
  /* bg image of pseudo element */
  animation: fade 1s; /* call the animation */

}

 /* define the animation */     

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fade {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-o-keyframes fade {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes fade {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

JQuery

```
(function($) {
  $('.clicker').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

**Best I can do with limited JQ skills but based on your stated requirements. an inline image would simplify things enormously**